# How to manipulate li tags to act like a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-tables

I have a list of li tags inside a ul, and I want to change the order they appear to the client, instead of one after another I want them in order like a simple table I build.

The table

```
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;width: 300px; height: 300px;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-  style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font- weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-  width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
</style>
<table class="tg">
<tr>
<th class="tg-031e" colspan="2">Item 1</th>
</tr>                 
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Item 2</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Item 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Item 4</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Item 5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="tg-031e">Item 6</td>
<td class="tg-031e">Item 7</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and this is the ul

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 6</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

How can I achive this?

Comment: If you want a table, use a table not a list.

Comment: its kinda trick because i am using a jquery plug based on ul/li

Answer (score 1):

If the data is tabular, it probably makes sense to use a table for it.

But if it's a navigation list or similar, you can style your `li` using [the `display` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#display-prop) to make them appear in a row. The values `inline`, `inline-block`, or even `table-cell` would all work.

```css
#sortable2 li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
<li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 6</li>
</ul>
```